# Using jquery to ref a Dropdown decrements my dropdown array?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use $.data() for the first time.  I want to store some data...append that data to a label but I don't know if this $.data() can be used to append to ANY DOM element such as labels, you name it or only to elements such as divs and specific elements like that.

```
$('#myLabelID').data({"carId":carId, "carName":carName});
alert("the value stored for carId is: " + $('#myLabelID').data("carId"));
```

It seems to get to my alert but it's saying that the value carId is undefined so I don't know if my first line is right.  I know carId has a value.

I want to be able to retrieve this data later on for specific reasons...do I don't know if I can stash it in this label or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this instead to store data in your dom element.

```
$('#myLabelID').data('carId', {"carId":carId, "carName":carName});
```

Any dom element can store data

For retrieval use this

```
alert("the value stored for carId is: " + $('#myLabelID').data("carId").carId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong, you should do::

```
$('#myLabelID').data("cardId", "carId");//sets cardId
$('#myLabelID').data("carName", "carName");
alert("the value stored for carId is: " + $('#myLabelID').data("carId"));
```

You can also save an object:

```
$('#myLabelID').data("myObject", {carId:"carId", carName:"carName"});

alert($('#myLabelID').data("myObject").carId);
```

Comment: I am still getting undefined on that alert even though I've got a valid carId that I'm trying to store...